# FT-450D not transmitting with microphone

Tags: digital-modes, transmitter, equipment-troubleshooting, microphone, ft-450d

I've been using FT8 on my Yaesu FT-450D for quite some time. I decided to try to talk on phone frequencies and discovered neither one of my mics will transmit. My mics are the original hand mic and a Heil headset. I've tried all bands and cannot transmit on any of them. I had successfully talked on the radio but not now. The only change I have made was to change from a switching power supply to a linear power supply. The radio will not transmit on either supply. It only transmits in digital modes. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How is the FT8 audio fed into your trx? What happens when you press the PTT switch on your hand microphone?

Comment: Hello Lyndon, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Comment: Microphone gain accidentially set to 0?

Answer (score 1):

Try changing mode from DATA-USB to USB/LSB.

Comment: I change the mode to USB/LSB with no effect.

Comment: Hello and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

My Xiegu G90 radio has to have the output from the 8-pin connector in the back set to line instead of mic for it to transmit a digital signal into my SignalLink sound card. Could it be that the FT-450D has the same type of settings. which may need to be changed back again from line to mic to send SSB or voice.

Comment: Hello Lewis, and welcome to ham.stackexchange.com!

Answer (score 1):

It appears that the 450 has a number of complex settings that may well be the source of your problem. Here's some feedback from other owners who've learned some interesting features on their radios:

[Yaesu FT-450D settings](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mbQJSHYFCsU)

[Yaesu FT-450D solution 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BkCiYZK0A10)

I'm thinking that your trouble is merely an unintended setting in the menu system.